# Do I need to consider possible re-entrant coding issues when using the await operator in an extension method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, reentrancy

I am going to use this method in a Load Test which means thousands of calls may happen very quickly from different threads.  I am wondering if I have to consider what would happen on subsequent call, where a new WebClient is created but before the prior await is complete?

```
    public static async Task<string> SendRequest(this string url)
    {
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            var bytes = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

I use the term reentrant to describe the fact that this method will be called by one or more threads.

Comment: Nope, it is as clean as it possibly could be. Nicely done

Comment: As an aside, any reason for using DownloadDataTaskAsync rather than just `DownloadStringTaskAsync`? That would cut the 5 lines in the middle down to one...

Comment: No reason, just new at using WebClient, thanks for the tip Jon...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Got you covered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So we want to know what potential problems could arise from using this method in a multithreaded context, either through a single call in an environment that has multiple threads, or where multiple calls are being made from one or more threads.

The first thing to look at is what does this method expose externally.  If we're designing this method, we can control what it does, but not what the callers do.  We need to assume that anyone can do anything with whatever they pass into our method, what they do with the returned value, and what they do with the type/object instance that the class is called on.  Let's look at each of these in turn.

The URL:

Obviously the caller can pass in an invalid URL, but that's not an issue that's specific to asynchrony or multithreading.  They can't really do anything else with this parameter.  They can't mutate the string from another thread after passing it to us, because `string` is immutable (or at least observably immutable externally).

The return value:

So at first glance, this in fact may appear to be a problem.  We're returning an object instance (a `Task`); that object is being mutated by this method that we're writing (to mark it as faulted, excepted, completed) and it is also likely to be mutated by the caller of this method (to add continuations).  It's also quite plausible for this `Task` to end up being mutated from multiple different threads (the task could be passed to any number of other threads, which could mutate it by adding continuations, or be reading values while we're mutating it).

Fortunately, `Task` was very specifically designed to support all of these situations, and it will function properly due to the synchronization that it performs internally.  As authors of this method, we don't need to *care* who adds what continuations to our task, from what thread, whether or not different people are adding them at the same time, what order things happen in, whether continuations are added before or after we mark the task as completed, or any of that.  While the task can be mutated externally, even from other threads, there's nothing that they could do that would be observable to us, from this method.  Likewise, their continuations are going to function appropriately regardless of what *we* do.  Their continuations will always fire some time after the task is marked as completed, or immediately if it was already completed.  It doesn't have the possible race conditions that an event based model has of adding an event handler after the event is fired to signal completion.

Finally, we have state of the type/instance.

This one is easy.  It's a `static` method, so there are no instance fields that we could access even if we wanted to.  There are also no static fields that this method accesses, so no state is shared between threads that way that we need to be concerned about.

Other than the string input and task output, the state that this method uses is entirely local variables that are never accessible outside of this method.  Since *this method* does everything in a single thread (if there is a synchronization context, or it at least does everything sequentially even if thread pool threads are used), we don't need to worry about any threading issues internally, only what could be happening externally by the caller.

When you're concerned about methods being called multiple times before previous calls have finished, the primary concern here is around access to fields.  If the method was accessing instance/static fields, then one would need to consider the implications not only of a method being called with any given input state, but also with what's going on if other methods are accessing those fields at the same time.  Since we access none, this is moot *for this method*.